# "TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of null" for multiple requests

Tags: node.js, postgresql, angular, express, sequelize.js

I'm building an angular node app rating system. In that system Im trying to loop through an array of ids that were sent as a POST req to the server and push those ids using a for loop into the users need to rate column.

The first user is successfully getting the entire loop pushed, but the next user fails at the second index. After debugging, I've found that the backend is receiving all of the correct variables, I dont understand why its not working for user two but is for user one.

Here is my backend code

```
 addRatee: function addRatee(req,res) {
    var decoded = jwt.decode(req.query.token);
    return model.User.findById(req.params.raterId)
      .then(function (user) {
      for (let ratee of req.body.rateeIds) {
        user.needToRate.push(ratee);
      }
      user.update({
        needToRate: user.needToRate
      }).then(function (updatedUser) {
        return res.status(200).json({
          title: "Successfully added users to need to rate",
          obj: updatedUser
        });
      }).catch(function () {
        return res.status(400).json({
          message: "Error updating user",
          error: err.toString()
        });
      });
    }).catch(function (e) {
      return res.status(400).json({
        message: "Error finding user",
        error: e.toString()
      });
    });
  }
```

Here is my component service code

```
 addRatee(rateeIds: number[], raterId: number) {
    const headers = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
    const token = localStorage.getItem('token')
      ? '?token=' + localStorage.getItem('token')
      : '';
    const body = {
      rateeIds: rateeIds
    };
    return this.http.patch(this.devUrl + '/new-ratee/' + raterId + token, body, {headers: headers});
  }
```

And here is my component.ts code

```
let dRateeIds = [this.trip.rider1Id, this.trip.rider2Id, this.trip.rider3Id];
              let r1RateeIds = [this.trip.driverId, this.trip.rider2Id, this.trip.rider3Id];
              let r2RateeIds = [this.trip.rider1Id, this.trip.driverId, this.trip.rider3Id];
              let r3RateeIds = [this.trip.rider1Id, this.trip.rider2Id, this.trip.driverId];
                  this.tripService.addRatee(dRateeIds, this.trip.driverId)
                    .subscribe(updatedUser => {
                      console.log(updatedUser);
                      this.tripService.addRatee(r1RateeIds, this.trip.rider1Id)
                        .subscribe(updatedUser2 => {
                          console.log(updatedUser2);
                      this.tripService.addRatee(r2RateeIds, this.trip.rider2Id)
                        .subscribe(updatedUser3 => {
                          console.log(updatedUser3);
                          this.tripService.addRatee(r3RateeIds, this.trip.rider3Id)
                            .subscribe(updatedUser4 => {
                              console.log(updatedUser4);
                            }, resp => console.log(resp));
                        }, resp => console.log(resp));
                    }, resp => console.log(resp));
                }, resp => console.log(resp));
```

I'm fairly new to programming so my code is kind of chaotic, I'm just looking for reasons for this error occuring.

Here is the full error stack given.

```
{"message":"Error finding user","error":"TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of null\n    at /Users/jonathancorrin/Desktop/workspace/atlas-web/server/controllers/trips.js:1380:24\n    at tryCatcher (/Users/jonathancorrin/Desktop/workspace/atlas-web/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/util.js:16:23)\n    at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (/Users/jonathancorrin/Desktop/workspace/atlas-web/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:512:31)\n    at Promise._settlePromise (/Users/jonathancorrin/Desktop/workspace/atlas-web/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:569:18)\n    at Promise._settlePromise0 (/Users/jonathancorrin/Desktop/workspace/atlas-web/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:614:10)\n    at Promise._settlePromises (/Users/jonathancorrin/Desktop/workspace/atlas-web/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:693:18)\n    at Async._drainQueue (/Users/jonathancorrin/Desktop/workspace/atlas-web/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:133:16)\n    at Async._drainQueues (/Users/jonathancorrin/Desktop/workspace/atlas-web/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:143:10)\n    at Immediate.Async.drainQueues (/Users/jonathancorrin/Desktop/workspace/atlas-web/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:17:14)\n    at runCallback (timers.js:781:20)\n    at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:743:5)\n    at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:714:5)"}
```

This is what my pgadmin table looks like after a few unsuccessful attempts. The null values being for users 2-4

[image]

****** UPDATE 
Here are the values logged when logging the needsToRate column before configuration and the value type

USER NEED TO RATE====== null
USER TYPE NTR========== object

Answer (score 1):

This issue was that I was trying to push values into a null field. I fixed the issue with this code

```
 for (let ratee of req.body.rateeIds) {
        if (user.needToRate === null) {
          user.needToRate = [];
          user.needToRate.push(ratee)
        } else {
          user.needToRate.push(ratee)
        }
      }
```